# How to update VS projects' frameworks from 2.0 to 4.0 safely?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, .net-2.0

We have about 5 big projects in 2.0 .NET framework. We are using VS 2008. We are decided to change our framework to 4.0 and upgrading to VS 2012. What are the possible problems in this situation? Which ways or steps should we follow? Any suggestions?

Comment: Open it up in 2012, it will offer to do the upgrade for you and list any problems during the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that can be suggested is: test it. The actual upgrade should be pretty simple. You may get a few warnings or errors where types or methods have been marked `[Obsolete]`, in which case it usually advises you on the type/method to look at for a replacement, however there can also be implementation changes that impact *some* (minority of) code. For example, sometimes a bug-fix can lead to your previously working code... *not* working (if you were inadvertently or deliberately using a behaviour that was not guaranteed).

There is no magic wand here; you just need to test it, but it shouldn't be **too** painful, especially if you have a test suite.

Also: if you're doing an upgrade *anyway*, why not go to 4.5?

Comment: thanks Marc Gravell, we have to do too much test after upgrading them. Yes you are right, I will share your idea with others about upgrading to 4.5